# Is there a module which tries to fit different functions to set of data points?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, data-fitting

Let’s say I have 100 data points, consisting of two values (x,y or V1, V2).

Right now I am defining a  bunch of functions (like log, exp, poly, sigmoid etc.) with a bunch of parameters to scale the data and/or adapt the base-equation. Then I use scipy.optimize.minimize to fit them to the data. After that I compare the fits visually  and by their rms to choose the best one.

Is there a python module which does that?

Comment: My open source Python curve fitting web site, zunzun.com, has a "function finder" that does equation search similar to what you describe using the Differential Evolution genetic algorithm to determine initial parameter estimates for any non-linear equations. It will fit your data to hundreds of known, named equations. The function finder URL is http://zunzun.com/FunctionFinder__A___/2/ and it comes with example data for testing. After glancing through the available options, just hit the Submit button at the top of the page to give it a spin.

Answer (score 0):

In scipy there is curve_fit but I believe you have to define the curve that is going into it.